# fetching Ads using google custom search API

Tags: google-custom-search

Is it possible to fetch **ads** is search results using the google custom search API ?
Need this to do a simple experiment. Search something and to see if any ad appears in the results.
Is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to screen scrap the search result window. Use some tool like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and inspect the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could open one Google AdWords account and there you can make sample queries and experiments and whatever you want.

Google are not really a big fan of the experiments on their front-end, on Google AdSense, on Google CSE, CSA, etc. You could try, but you might get a wrong picture - there are some protection algorithms on the front-end.